# ¿Como hago consulta sql para restar 2 campos de 2 tablas y actualizar una de ellas con el resultado

Tags: c#, sql

Buenas tardes talves me puedan ayudar, con esta consulta,lo que quiero hacer es que se actualize la columna stockactual_di de la tabla talmacen pero unicamente se APLIQUE a aquellos productos que coincidan con el mismo idproducto de la tabla almacen con el idarticulo de la tabla detalleingreso
`inner join tdetalleingreso on tdetalleingreso.idarticulo=talmacen.idproducto` de igual forma el idingreso sea igual con las tabla almacen y tabla ingreso  `inner join tingreso on tingreso.idingreso=talmacen.id_ingreso` tomando en cuenta que el estado sea igual DEV.

se es de suponer q solamente tomaria encuente lo siguiente

```
tingreso  tdetalleingreso talmacen
1029      1029            1029     

despues 
tabla tdetalleingres                   tabla talmacen

idingreso idarticulo   stockactual     idingreso    idproducto stockactua_di
1029       999           3              1029          999         4
1029       888           3              1029          888         4
1029       777           3              1029          777         4

se hace la resta y se actualiza  y en la tabla talmacen  queda asi
stockactua_di
      1
      1
      1
```

pero lo que obtengo es esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

talves me orientan como seria la consulta

```
UPDATE talmacen
set 
talmacen.stockactual_di=talmacen.stockactual_di - tdetalleingreso.stockactual 
from talmacen
inner join tdetalleingreso on tdetalleingreso.idarticulo=talmacen.idproducto
inner join tingreso on tingreso.idingreso=talmacen.id_ingreso
where tingreso.estado='DEV'
```

tabla ingreso

[image: tabla ingreso]

tabla detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla almacen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas hacer eso en C#?

Comment: Si. Cuando haga una devolucion de ese ingreso por algun motivo. en la tabla ingreso se actualiza el campo estado y q se ejecurata la consulta para restar el stock q esta en la tabla almacen.  Esa es la idea.

Comment: en la imagen numero3 de la tabla tdetalleingres hay articulos con el mismo codigo pero pertenecen a otro IDINGRESO, lo que esta haciendo es tomar los primero 3 y hace la resta sin tomar en cuenta que sea con el idingreso=1029. ahi le seguire buscando cuando puedan me hechan una mano al codigo

Answer (score -1):

Lo que buscas sería algo así:

```
SUM(campo1 - campo2) As resultado
```

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo y explicación en este video de Youtube https://youtu.be/nO0QMp6Go8A

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/368020)